# Multiform Wizard Save Data and Store Session in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I need to design a form using (multiform wizard or stepper) that saves Data in different tables, Suppose a user fills three forms and saves the data in three different tables, the next time the user login the form should start from the 4th stage, and the user can also edit the save form, the tables are different it does not save in one table how to design such multiform in laravel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example you created form of 4 pages.

When user filled up to 2 form and it stores in 2 tables.

Now when user logged out and came back again. U will have to check in DB weather the user's data was entered in table or not .

If it was entered then u must open that form as edit mode and skip to load that page. If the entry is missing in the table then you have to open that form in create mode with showing that page as active.